# It does not insert all rows (VBA)

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I want to insert a huge file starting from the 1.000.000th row of the file (total row number is 1.337.550) but it inserts only 48578 rows. Why, and how can I insert all rows from 1.000.000th (this or the other way)?

```
Sub Inserter()

    Dim ConOrg As String
    ConOrg = "TEXT;" & Cells(1, 4).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "support"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= ConOrg, Destination:=Cells(1, 1))
        .Name = filename
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFileStartRow = 1000000
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: But if I insert from the 1.000.000th row the excel should hold only 337.550 rows.

Comment: This seems to be pretty strange, I have tried to start from row `2667537` and it only inserts 1 row. I guess these are some internal optimizations from Excel, helping you to avoid some out-of-range error.